# Unable to execute foreach within foreach in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Please see an excerpt of the code I am using the code below:

```
foreach ($citydisplay as $display){
  foreach ($arrlat as $eastings){}
  foreach ($arrlong as $northings){}
  echo '<pre>'; print_r ($display[0]); echo '</pre>';
  echo '<pre>'; print_r ($eastings[0][0]); echo '</pre>';
  echo '<pre>'; print_r ($northings[0][0]); echo '</pre>';
}
```

$citydisplay is an array; $arrlat is an array; and $arrlong is an array.

Please see an excerpt of what the code returns:

```
Abbotsford
-37.818868000
144.872823000
Albion
-37.818868000
144.872823000
Altona Meadows
-37.818868000
144.872823000
```

From the result it returns each city name but returns the same lat and lng values for each city. I have tried adjusting the curly brackets but it doesn't return the results in the order I want; I would like each city to display its corresponding lat and lng values.
Please how do I resolve this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not the way to use several foreach loops.

If your three variables have the same indexes, and if you are sure of it, you could try something like :

```
foreach ($citydisplay as $index => $display) {
  echo '<pre>'; print_r ($display[0]); echo '</pre>';
  echo '<pre>'; print_r ($arrlat[$index][0][0]); echo '</pre>';
  echo '<pre>'; print_r ($arrlong[$index][0][0]); echo '</pre>';
}
```

Otherwise, you have to change your structures

Comment: Malet: Yea, it works. Please before I select it as the accepted answer, please kindly change the first line of your answer to: foreach ($citydisplay as $index => $display) {

Comment: Thanks for notifying, I'm a bit rusty